# How does windows file sharing actually work?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, file-transfer, tcp

I know that when communicating over HTTP, the source has to be downloaded first to be viewed on the browser. But what mechanism is actually at play when using windows file sharing (Both when sharing over a network router and sharing directly e.g a LAN cable from PC-1 to PC-2)?

1. Is a request sent to the server, which starts transmitting data on a certain port to be received by the client?
2. Does the client access the server's drive like a conventional drive, read data and copy it to it's own drive?

   3. Does the server copy the file to the client's hard disk?

Comment: I just added a quoted answers from Microsoft resources for how Windows file sharing works protocol and authentication wise. This should tell you what you need for all your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How does windows file sharing actually work?**

> ### <sub>[Microsoft SMB Protocol Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365234(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
>
> <sub>The security model used in Microsoft SMB Protocol is identical to the
>   one used by other variants of SMB, and consists of two levels of
>   security—user and share. A share is a file, directory, or printer that
>   can be accessed by Microsoft SMB Protocol clients.</sub>
>
> <sub>User-level authentication indicates that the client attempting to
>   access a share on a server must provide a user name and password. When
>   authenticated, the user can then access all shares on a server not
>   also protected by share-level security. This security level allows
>   system administrators to specifically determine which users and groups
>   can access a share.</sub>
>
> <sub>Share-level authentication indicates that access to a share is
>   controlled by a password assigned to that share only. Unlike
>   user-level security, this security level does not require a user name
>   for authentication and no user identity is established.</sub>
>
> <sub>Under both of these security levels, the password is encrypted before
>   it is sent to the server. NTLM and the older LAN Manager (LM)
>   encryption are supported by Microsoft SMB Protocol. Both encryption
>   methods use challenge-response authentication, where the server sends
>   the client a random string and the client returns a computed response
>   string that proves the client has sufficient credentials for access.</sub>
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365234(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>

---

> ### <sub>[Microsoft SMB Protocol and CIFS Protocol Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
>
> <sub>The Server Message Block (SMB) Protocol is a network file sharing
>   protocol, and as implemented in Microsoft Windows is known as
>   Microsoft SMB Protocol. The set of message packets that defines a
>   particular version of the protocol is called a dialect. The Common
>   Internet File System (CIFS) Protocol is a dialect of SMB. Both SMB and
>   CIFS are also available on VMS, several versions of Unix, and other
>   operating systems.</sub>
>
> <sub>The technical reference to CIFS is available from Microsoft
>   Corporation at [Common Internet File System (CIFS) File Access
>   Protocol](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84095).</sub>
>
> <sub>Although its main purpose is file sharing, additional Microsoft SMB
>   Protocol functionality includes the following:</sub>
>
> - <sub>[Dialect negotiation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365235(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
> - <sub>Determining other Microsoft SMB Protocol servers on the network, or    network browsing</sub>
> - <sub>Printing over a network</sub>
> - <sub>[File, directory, and share access authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365234(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
> - <sub>File and record locking</sub>
> - <sub>File and directory change notification</sub>
> - <sub>Extended file attribute handling</sub>
> - <sub>Unicode support</sub>
> - <sub>[Opportunistic locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365433(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
>
> <sub>In the OSI networking model, Microsoft SMB Protocol is most often used
>   as an Application layer or a Presentation layer protocol, and it
>   relies on lower-level protocols for transport. The transport layer
>   protocol that Microsoft SMB Protocol is most often used with is
>   NetBIOS over TCP/IP
>   ([NBT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870909(v=vs.85).aspx)).
>   However, Microsoft SMB Protocol can also be used without a separate
>   transport protocol—the Microsoft SMB Protocol/NBT combination is
>   generally used for backward compatibility.</sub>
>
> <sub>The Microsoft SMB Protocol is a client-server implementation and
>   consists of a set of data packets, each containing a request sent by
>   the client or a response sent by the server. These packets can be
>   broadly classified as follows:</sub>
>
> - <sub>Session control packets—Establishes and discontinues a connection to    shared server resources.</sub>
> - <sub>File access packets—Accesses and manipulates files and directories on    the remote server.</sub>
> - <sub>General message packets—Sends data to print queues, mailslots, and    named pipes, and provides data about the status of print queues.</sub>
>
> <sub>Some message packets may be grouped and sent in one transmission to
>   reduce response latency and increase network bandwidth. This is called
>   "batching." The [Microsoft SMB Protocol Packet Exchange
>   Scenario](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365236(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   section describes an example of a Microsoft SMB Protocol session that
>   uses packet batching.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> <sub>**Topic:** [Microsoft SMB Protocol Dialects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365235(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** To establish a connection between a client and a server using Microsoft SMB Protocol, you must first determine the
>     dialect with the highest level of functionality that both the client
>     and server support.</sub>
>
> <sub>**Topic:** [Microsoft SMB Protocol Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365234(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** The security model used in Microsoft SMB Protocol is identical to the one used by other variants of SMB, and consists of
>     two levels of security—user and share. A share is a file, directory,
>     or printer that can be accessed by Microsoft SMB Protocol clients.</sub>
>
> <sub>**Topic:** [Microsoft SMB Protocol Packet Exchange Scenario](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365236(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** Example of a Microsoft SMB Protocol packet exchange between a client and a server.</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub></sub>

---

### Comment Clarification

*File access packets—Accesses and manipulates files and directories on the remote server.' How does this happen? Where is the response packet to give the requested data to client?* [Kraken](https://superuser.com/users/464420/kraken)

> <sub>Each packet is typically a basic request of some kind, such as open
>   file, close file, or read file.  The server then receives the packet,
>   checks to see if the request is legal, verifies the client has the
>   appropriate file permissions, and finally executes the request and
>   returns a response packet to the client.  The client then parses the
>   response packet and can determine whether or not the initial request
>   was successful.</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>[source](http://www.codefx.com/CIFS_Explained.htm)</sub></sub>

---

### Further Resources

<sup>A diagram and an explanation of the authentication aspects involved in establishing a client-server session with the protocol.</sup>

- [3.2.4.2.4.1 Sequence Diagram](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246380.aspx)

  [image]

<sup>Reads for further detail on SMB.</sup>

- [Microsoft SMB, SMB2, NetBIOS, WINS protocol suite](http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/ms-smb-protocols.html)
- [Server Message Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)
- [Server Message Block Protocol (SMB)](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SMB)

Comment: 'File access packets—Accesses and manipulates files and directories on the remote server.' Exactly my question. How does this happen? Where is the response packet to give the requested data to client?

Comment: @Kraken See the bottom of my answer with the **Comment Clarification**  and then **Further Resources** detail.

Comment: Thank you. That is definitely what I needed to know. +1 for clarification.

Comment: So it is basically not that different from HTTP.